# How to fix: NUnit unit tests not showing up in testing pad in Visual Studio Community (Mac)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

In spite of adding NUnit from NuGet to an existing .Net Core project, no unit tests are being shown in the Test Pad.

Note: I posted these images as links because I have too low of a reputation to post images.  What's up with that?

1. [Project > Add NuGet Packages...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIbAO.png)
2. [Selected NUnit Package (3.11.0) and clicked "Add Package"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dSGw.png)
3. [Checked to see if added to solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ccao.png)
4. Created a new empty class file within the solution
5. Added tests to this class
6. [No tests show up in the test pad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIloT.png)

I've tried restarting Visual Studio and reinstalling the package.

I've also tried deleting the Project/obj directory -- still no luck.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
namespace ExampleLib
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ExampleTestFixture
    {
        [Test]
        public void ExampleTest()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(2, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Expected: Tests fill the Unit Test pad
Actual:  Empty test pad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple requirements of that project, so that VS for Mac can identify and execute the test cases.

1. The project must be a console application of .NET Core.
2. The project must have a reference of `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` (required by VSTest infrastructure).
3. The project must have a reference of `NUnit`.
4. The project must have a reference of `NUnit3TestAdapter` (required by VSTest infrastructure).

Example,

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Note that VS for Windows and VS for Mac (and JetBrains Rider) all use VSTest for unit testing, so this setup works for all such IDEs.

Also note that if you didn't create this console project from `dotnet new nunit`, but a normal console application template, you need to manually delete the `Main` method.

Comment: I added that to an existing project and it gave me an issue about there being more than one Main.  Then I ran `dotnet new nunit` within the root project directory and it removed the error.  Could you add that to this answer?  Thanks so much for your help.  Not sure why it would be this much different between the two templates.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I added the    `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />` line

Answer (score 1):

The NuGet package only allows you to use the NUnit framework to write tests. In other words, it's like adding references to the NUnit DLLs.

You need to install the [adapter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnit3TestAdapter) to see the tests.

Comment: That's not for Visual Studio Community edition (MacOS).   I can't even open up that file.
It says Visual Studio 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017 in the package.

Comment: @shua Try installing it by going to Tools > Extensions from the VS menu bar. I am not sure if that extension supports MacOS but they it that way. If it doesn't, then unfortunately you are out of luck and you just have to use visual studio's unit testing framework.

Comment: You probably pointed to the wrong link, https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/3.12.0 The adapter is a NuGet package.

Comment: @CodingYoshi There's no Tools > Extensions option.

Comment: @LexLi, I was able to install the NUnit3TestAdapter, but the tests still aren't showing up.  I've tried restarting Visual Studio, cleaning both the project and the solution, and creating a new console application entirely.  Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As [lex-li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) comments, you should install the **nuget version** of the adapter (https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/3.12.0).
You install this into your solution, preferably for all test projects.

(The adapter on the marketplace is the vsix adapter, which can be installed into VS itself - but this practice is not recommended and as you points out, doesn't even seem to work for Mac Community version.)

Comment: This still yields no results.